# Как поменять версию python по умолчанию в Google colab на 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-colaboratory

В Google colab есть код, который работал на python 3.7. Сейчас в Google colab python 3.8 - библиотеки отказываются даже импортироваться и работать.

Подскажите рабочий способ, как поменять версию python по умолчанию в Google Colab на версию 3.7?
Установить pip соответствующий версии 3,7.

Чтобы вернуть среду к тому состоянию, который был при python 3.7.

Пробовал через установку анаконды как написано здесь (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867581/install-python-3-7-via-google-colab-as-default-python)

```
!wget -qO ac.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./ac.sh -b
```

не получилось

Пробовал через установку инсталляцию и установку переменной окружения:

```
!apt-get install python3.7
!bash virtualenv env --python=python3.7
```

не сработало

Пробовал ещё так:

```
!apt-get install python3.7
!sudo apt install python3.7-dev
!sudo apt install python3.7-venv
```

После чего запрос на версию

```
!python3 --version
```

начал выдавать: Python 3.7.16

Но с pip так и не получилось - работает версия pip для python 3.8

```
!pip3 --version
```

выдаёт pip 22.0.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

и эта версия pip неверно подтягивает библиотеки.

Comment: А какие библиотеки у вас перестали работать в 3.8? Просто даже интересно. А так то `pip` вы можете запустить какой нужно, если укажете ему полный путь для запуска.

Comment: @CrazyElf, перестали грузиться определенные версии библиотек, которые использовал год назад, н-р '```!pip install -q tensorflow==2.1
!pip install -q keras==2.3.1
!pip install -q tensorflow-estimator==2.1``` Вот ссылка на блокнот, чтобы детальнее было https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17-OaCdrY0cEu_jKvNG2wNjRGPbhd674H?usp=sharing

Comment: А вам точно нужны строго эти версии библиотек? Не пробовали отвязаться от конкретных версий?

Comment: @CrazyElf, уже пытаюсь. Но подумал, что если удастся всё вернуть к прежней версии, то всё будет проще - не надо будет ничего править

Answer (score 0):

В анаконде можно менять версии.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В анаконде да, но как сделать так чтобы по умолчанию в колабе была версия python используемая анакондой и соответствующая версия pip?